# Get all the commits message of a file using GitPython

Tags: gitpython

I have the following piece of code to get the list of commit summaries of a specific file:

```py
from git import Repo
repo_working_dir = '<valid directory of the repo>'

repo = Repo(repo_working_dir)

update_file = '<full path of the file whose commit summaries I want to read>'
for commit in list(repo.iter_commits(repo.active_branch,paths=update_file)):
    print(commit.summary)
```

The above code runs but returns no output. Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: I'm guessing `Repo.iter_commits` expects a path relative to the git root, and is given a full path. In that case nothing would match and thus nothing would print resulting in no output. Documentation of gitpython does not clarify this at all

Comment: Thanks I tried passing the path relative to the git root and still it returns nothing